# Django Ajax form validation

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to do ajax form validation to display errors. I looked at many examples, but some are old and do not work, while others I do not understand.Below is the code, please help with the implementation of ajax requests.

views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        # Set the chosen password
        new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
        # Save the User object
        new_user.save()
        return HttpResponse('IZI')
    else:
        print(user_form.errors)
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        # errors = user_form.errors
        data = {'user_form': user_form, 'errors': user_form.errors}
        return render(request, 'registration.html', data)
        # return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(errors))
else:
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'registration.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

models.py

```
class TestUser(AbstractUser):
phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = '"fyzzys"."users"'
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
phone = PhoneNumberField(region='RU', required='true')
email = forms.CharField(error_messages='')

class Meta:
    model = TestUser
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email', 'phone')

def clean_password2(self):
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
    return cd['password2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example but you'll need to adapt it to your needs and your code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
$.ajax({
        url: 'your_url_for_register_view',
        data: { password : 'your_password',
                password2 : 'your_password',
                phone : 'your_phone',
                email : 'your_email',
                csrfmiddlewaretoken : {{ csrf_token }},
              },
        success: function (data) {
            //do something if successful
        }
      });
</script>
```

*As per documentation : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html*